# Mysql returning OK but with no results

Tags: mysql

When I try to run a select statement with subqueries in mysql workbench I encounter an OK response with no results (the query is successful). I am sure the code is alright and mysql also doesn't find any error, but I don't know why I don't get any answer.

Here's the code

```
SELECT date(created_at),
    (SELECT 
            SUM(amount) AS topup_amount
        FROM
            wallet_transaction
        WHERE
            type = 'topup'
        GROUP BY DATE(created_at)),
    (SELECT 
            SUM(amount) AS admin_add_amount
        FROM
            wallet_transaction
        WHERE
            type = 'admin_add'
        GROUP BY DATE(created_at))
FROM
    wallet_transaction;
```

Comment: Well, have you checked that records exist that match the query? Can you show them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are after the result produced by a query like this:

```
SELECT DATE(wt.created_at)                                    AS dt_created 
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(wt.type = 'topup'    , wt.amount, 0)),0) AS topup_amount
     , IFNULL(SUM(IF(wt.type = 'admin_add', wt.amount, 0)),0) AS admin_add_amount
  FROM wallet_transaction wt
 GROUP BY DATE(wt.created_at)
```

---

There are a couple of issues with the original query. The subqueries in the SELECT list can return at most one row, or MySQL will throw an error.

Comment: thanks @spencer7593 a lot, it worked perfectly, i learned a lot

Comment: What a difficult to debug "error message", it's quite a thing trying to debug legacy code that *rarely* has non-limited subqueries that return multiple results

Comment: @BrianLeishman:  I suspect that MySQL was actually throwing an error, and OP code wasn't checking for it. But that's just a guess, there's not enough information provided to make that diagnosis. So I just skipped the debugging. And without example data and not sample of expected output, I just took a guess at a specification, and wrote a query to satisfy that spec.

Comment: I had a similar problem to the OP and in my case it turned out to be an error in the MySQL syntax.  Creating a union seemed to get it to display the error I needed.  I did something like this SELECT MyFunction() UNION SELECT MyFunction();

Comment: @spencer7593 I don't think so, it seems that even in Workbench sometimes you just get "OK", can happen if you have a subquery that returns more than row sometimes, or I have a case now where a UDF does it with some input sometimes with no errors (log or returned)

Comment: @BrianLeishman: you don't think so, what, that a subquery as an expression in SELECT list should return one column and no more than one row, or that I don't suspect that MySQL is throwing an error? As to the answer I provided, I'm fairly certain that my statement about subqueries as expression in a SELECT list should not return more than one row. The behavior observed by OP could also be due to an empty `wallet_transaction` table. As I mentioned in my previous comment, there wasn't enough information provided for a definitive diagnosis. But I'm sure OP query is malformed for general case.

Comment: @BrianLeishman: for workbench (or whatever client) returning "OK" and no resultset when SQL is malformed, again, I don't have a definitive diagnosis for the observed behavior; that's not something I dug into, I'm more focused on writing SQL that works,  Another way to get OP SQL to "work" would be to add `LIMIT 1` clause to each of the subqueries. work in double quotes because that only addresses the "returning more than one row" bit, but SQL doesn't return the resultset that OP is really after. I took at guess at a specification and demonstrated a query that satisfies it.